# How to pass template to grandchild carousel's #slides slot (vue3-carousel)

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue3-carousel

I need to create a BaseSlider component. in this component, I use vue3-carousel. Here is the BaseSlider code:

```
<template>
    <div class="mv-slide">
        <carousel ref="carousel" v-model="currentSlide" :items-to-show="1">
            <slot />
            <template #addons v-if="arrow">
                <navigation>
                    <template #next>
                        <span> >> </span>
                    </template>
                    <template #prev>
                        <span>
                            dsa </span>
                    </template>
                </navigation>
            </template>
        </carousel>
        <div class="mv-slide__pagination" v-if="indicator">
            <div v-for="slide in 11" :class="{
                'mv-slide__pagination-item': true,
                'mv-slide__pagination-item--active': currentSlide === slide
            }" @click="currentSlide = slide"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Here is how I use the BaseSlider

```
<BaseSlider>
      <Slide v-for="slide in 10" :key="slide">
                <img src="http://localhost:3000/custom-estimate-mv1.png" alt="custom estimate"
                    class="mv-slide___img">
        </Slide>
 </BaseSlider>
```

My app is crashed with this code with error

[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of render function
at <Carousel ref="carousel" modelValue=0 onUpdate:modelValue=fnonUpdate:modelValue  ... >

Cannot set properties of null (setting 'index')

at Array.forEach ()

Does anyone have experience on create component wraping vue3-carousel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass the slides over your `BaseSlider` component, then your `default` slot gets a parent Vnode containing all your slides as children.

This means, To access slides you should go over `slots.default()[0].children` and the `Carousel` is not prepared for such scenario.

That's why the errors happens in the Carousel at the line

```
slidesElements.forEach((el, index) => (el.props.index = index));
```

since the parent Vnode does not have props.

I haven't found any way to fix it using templates, so I wrote a [Render Function](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#render-functions-jsx) for the `BaseSlider` that returns the `Carousel` and fills the default slot with the slides.

```
<script setup>
import { useSlots, h} from 'vue';
import { Carousel, Slide, Pagination, Navigation } from 'vue3-carousel';

const slots = useSlots()
const render = () => {
    return  h('div', { class: 'mv-slide' }, [
       h(Carousel, { 'items-to-show': 1 }, {
          default: () => slots.default()[0].children,
          addons: () => [ h(Navigation),  h(Pagination) ]
        })  
    ]);
};
</script>

<template>
    <render />
</template>
```

Here is the working [SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have found a solution with slots.default()[0].children like you too. But i found out that it just works with v-for, if I pass 2 <Slide /> tag to the default slot, It won't work

Comment: Yes, it does not work so. I would suggest you to look for another way to achieve your goal.